# why is my code endlessly testing (n queens problem / java / blue)

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking, bluej

so im currently working on an algorithm for the n queens problem and i think im done, however when i run a junit class to test the code its just endlessly working.

The blue bar just endlessly moves from left to right and so on (https://prnt.sc/ruqjef)

Im not quite sure why it is like that. The junit class is testing the code with n=8. When i try it with n=1 its working, when i try it with n>=2 its just loading/working.

I have no idea why, so i would really appreciaty some help c:

My code:

```
public class Damenproblem {

    /**
     * Datenstruktur für das Speichern der Damenpositionen
     * als Array-Attribut der Klasse
     */
    private boolean[][] damenFeld;

    /**
     * Gibt ein zweidimensionales boolean-Array zurueck. 
     * n ist die Schachbrettbreite. Auf den jeweiligen
     * Positionen des Arrays sind die Positionen der Damen (true = Dame, false =
     * keine Dame). Wenn sich das Problem nicht loesen laesst, wird eine
     * NoSolutionException geworfen.
     */
    public boolean[][] damen(int n) throws NoSolutionException{
        this.damenFeld = new boolean[n][n];
        if (setze(0)){
            return damenFeld;
        }
        else {
            throw new NoSolutionException();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Backtracking-Algorithmus
     * Parameter dameNr gibt die laufende Nummer der zu setzenden Dame an.
     */
    private boolean setze(int dameNr) {
        int zeile = 0;
        if(dameNr == damenFeld.length) {
            return true;
        } else {
        for(dameNr = 0; dameNr <= damenFeld.length; dameNr++) {

            if(erlaubt(dameNr, zeile)) {
                damenFeld[dameNr][zeile] = true;
                if(setze(dameNr+1)) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    damenFeld[dameNr][zeile] = false;
                    zeile += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    }
    // DameNr ist die Spalte
    public boolean erlaubt(int spalte, int zeile) {
        // check horizontal and vertical
        int tempSpalte = spalte;
        int tempZeile = zeile;
        for(int i = 0; i < damenFeld.length; i++) {
            if(damenFeld[i][zeile] || damenFeld[spalte][i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        // check diagonal
        // to upper right
        while(spalte >= 0 && spalte <= damenFeld.length && zeile >= 0 && zeile <= damenFeld.length){
            spalte = tempSpalte;
            zeile = tempZeile;
            if(damenFeld[spalte][zeile]) {
                return false;
            }
            spalte += 1;
            zeile -= 1;
        }
        // check diagonal
        // to lower right
        while(spalte >= 0 && spalte <= damenFeld.length && zeile >= 0 && zeile <= damenFeld.length){
            spalte = tempSpalte;
            zeile = tempZeile;
            if(damenFeld[spalte][zeile]) {
                return false;
            }
            spalte += 1;
            zeile += 1;
        }
        // check diagonal
        // to lower left
        while(spalte >= 0 && spalte <= damenFeld.length && zeile >= 0 && zeile <= damenFeld.length){
            spalte = tempSpalte;
            zeile = tempZeile;
            if(damenFeld[spalte][zeile]) {
                return false;
            }
            spalte -= 1;
            zeile += 1;
        }
        // check diagonal
        // to upper left
        while(spalte >= 0 && spalte <= damenFeld.length && zeile >= 0 && zeile <= damenFeld.length){
            spalte = tempSpalte;
            zeile = tempZeile;
            if(damenFeld[spalte][zeile]) {
                return false;
            }
            spalte -= 1;
            zeile -= 1;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: In `setze()` this doesn't look right: `for(dameNr = 0; dameNr <= damenFeld.length; dameNr++)` this is the same name as the passed parameter, aren't you losing the value this way?  I think you reversed the sense of `dameNr` and `zeile` there.

Comment: yeah i just realized. i changed dameNr=0 to i=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order not to override your dameNr parameter the for loop in your method setze() should look like this:

```
for(zeile = 0; zeile < damenFeld.length; zeile++)
```

Your erlaubt() check is the main problem though. I would recommend using *for* instead of *while* loops that define new temporary parameters each. Otherwise you keep using your passed parameters over an over again.